# Five charges on a pentagon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

If we keep five identical point charges at the five corners of a regular pentagon.
What will be the electric field at the centre.

I think it would be zero due to symmetry.. Please correct me if  I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm on your side.

Comment: Hi Sudhanshu and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It will be zero since if we sum up the Electric field from each charge at the center they will cancel out:

> "The electric field from multiple point charges can be obtained by taking the vector sum of the electric fields of the individual charges."
>   (Source: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/mulpoi.html)

You can imagine electric field lines extending from each charge radially; it can then be seen that when the field lines intersect at the center of a regular polygon, they must cancel.